# Including partial in every view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to add olark to every page on my website, so I've stuck the code into a partial in my shared folder.

How can I easily add this to every page? I've noticed theres a footer partial included on every page, could I tie it in with that somehow?

Comment: you must add this in layout Ref:- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 2):

You can include this partial inside `application.html.erb` layout file with `<%= render 'partial_folder/partial_name' %>`

Answer (score 0):

I have used the olark scipt in a partial in `_olark.html.erb` and included in `_footer.html.erb`

Comment: Actually, you can't render a partial inside another partial, as far as I remember

Comment: @LuizE. Are u sure abt that?

Comment: I tried this once, and didn't worked, but I don't recall why...but if you saying I can do this, so I must have made a mistake that time. No big deal

Answer (score 0):

You can add renderer of this partial to your application layout `views/layouts/application.html.erb`